# SQL Comma Split function for nth loop iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a dynamic integer variable where the count number is loaded dynamically.

```
iCount = 3 
or iCount = 10  ( dynamically number is loaded ).

I have to split the number as 1,2,3 for the iCount = 3
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 for the iCount = 10
and 1 for the iCount = 1.
```

How can we achive the split functionality through nth variable in SQL ?

Comment: Are you asking how to output a column with numbers from 1 to n?  Show what your desired result should look like,

Comment: i am trying to get the sql syntax to iterate the variable icount and restore it in a column with comma seperation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @iCount int = 10, @iCountRef varchar(100)

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 as i
UNION ALL
SELECT i+1
FROM cte
WHERE i < @iCount
)

SELECT @iCountRef = STUFF((
SELECT ',' + CAST(i as nvarchar(10))
FROM cte
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @iCountRef
```

Output for `3`:

```
1,2,3
```

Output for `1`:

```
1
```

Output for `10`:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: thanks you saved my life. i should read about stuff function more briefly. if you can tell a little about that function will also be great thanks.

Comment: Seems odd to have a recursive CTE to generate the numbers and then an XML PATH to concatenate as the recursive CTE could just do the concatenation whilst it's at it.

Comment: My pleasure! STUFF in this case required for take away first comma.

Comment: STUFF (character_expression (to work with), start position (we need first), length (we will change only first one), replaceWith_expression (replace with emptiness :)))

Comment: i have to store this output to another varchar variable. I  just tried by declare @iCountRef varchar(100). Set icountRef =  , I couldnt store it.

Comment: Put it in my answer. Please, check

Comment: @gofr1, will you please help me in this posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766643/sql-compare-varchar-variable-with-another-varchar-variable

Answer (score 4):

[A simpler version](http://rextester.com/NTQC51012)

```
DECLARE @iCount int = 10, @iCountRef varchar(100);


WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 1 as i, CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS S
UNION ALL
SELECT i+1, CAST(CONCAT(S, ',', i+1) AS VARCHAR(8000))
FROM cte
WHERE i < @iCount
)
SELECT @iCountRef =  S
FROM cte
Where i = @iCount;

SELECT @iCountRef
```